# Hackage - Where is the MonadReader implementation for ReaderT defined?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, hackage

I seem unable to find where two relatively simple Haskell methods are defined.

It's about `ReaderT`. I am looking for its implementation of `ask` and `local`, as requested by the `MonadReader` contract.

At https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/src/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html#ask I read:

```
instance Monad m => MonadReader r (ReaderT r m) where
  ask = ReaderT.ask
  local = ReaderT.local
```

but then I cannot find neither `ReaderT.ask` nor `ReaderT.local` anywhere.

It is the first time that I find no implementation by perusing Hackage.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file contains the import statement

```
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Reader as ReaderT (ask, local, reader)
```

so `ReaderT.ask` etc. refer to [that module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html), from the `transformers-0.3.0.0` package (the only listed dependency of `mtl-2.1.2`. If you look on the main Hackage page of each package you may note that these are not the newest versions of either package.)

In general, `transformers` and `mtl` define many functions of the same name, except that the `transformers` versions work only on the transformer type directly implementing the relevant effect, while `mtl` uses the `Monad*` class system to make them methods that can lift automatically to other, wrapping transformers.

For the directly implementing transformer, like in your case, the particular method instance used in `mtl` is usually just refering to the corresponding `transformer` function.